# Turn signal on causes whining in the sound system?

Tags: chevrolet, noise, audio, turn-signal, suburban

The turn signals on my 2007 Suburban LTZ cause a whining sound (apparently in the speakers) when the signal switch is on. The signals operate appropriately and blink at the correct rate and on either side (left and right) whether the lights are on or off. The whine seems to follow the engine speed.

Any clue how this could happen?

Comment: Does the noise continue on when the signal switches off, or does it only happen with the signal engaged?

Comment: It shuts off when the switch is off, but it also does not come on every time that the turn signals are on - just most of the time. I have read elsewhere that the rear ac/radio control is involved, but haven't checked it yet